# Connect to SharePoint using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am facing issue that my code to connect to SharePoint is connecting to site even when the wrong password is entered

```
clientContext = new ClientContext(txtURL.Text);

                string mypwd = txtpwd.Text;
                SecureString password = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in mypwd.ToCharArray()) password.AppendChar(c);
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(txtUSERID.Text, password);

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web);

                excelList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestExcelUpload");
                clientContext.Load(excelList);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Do you have anonymous access enabled?

Comment: No, anonymous access is not enabled